# Can we stack elements on top of HTML5 Video?

Tags: html, video

What I want is for example:

```
<video> = z-index: -1;
<div id="post"> = z-index: 0;
```

I've tried this to a certain degree... but it would be good to know if anyone has some concrete information on it. I'm new to H5 Video, and I know with Flash it is possible, but not for mobile devices (which I don't care about atm, can have some crappy fallback)

Thanks for any info in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can stack elements on top of html5 video using z-index, exactly as you described.  You can see my demo with this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/cJJwj/3/

And here's the code that I use in that fiddle:

HTML

```
<video width="200" height="200" 
    controls="controls" 
    src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Eisbach_surfen_v1.ogv">
</video>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

CSS

```
video {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: medium solid yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I should mention, however, that I tried using `z-index: -1;` for the video, and the video controls wouldn't work (in Firefox 5 beta and Chrome), but when I used `z-index: 0` instead, the controls worked fine.  I don't know why that is yet.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t worked with HTML5 video much either, but I know that the Vimeo HTML5 player seems to do exactly what you’re asking. They use `<div>` and even `<canvas>` above the video to render the playback controls, title, and other buttons.